# How to include external javascripts clientside with socket.io?

Tags: javascript, html, http, socket.io, client

I am trying to include "howler" into the http served by socket i.o. to clients. so that if an event gets triggered and distributed to the clients they get a sound notification.

i tried with the basic example from socket ios getting started page (the chat) from https://socket.io/get-started/chat/ and tried to include howler into the base index.html like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat with sound at load</title>
  </head>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>

  $(function () {

    var socket = io();

    $('form').submit(function(){
      socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
      $('#m').val('');
      return false;
    });
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });

  });

</script>
  <body>


    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>


  <script src="./howler.js"></script>

  <script>

    var sound = new Howl({
      src: ['sound.mp3']
    });

    sound.play();

  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

but i get a 404 not found Error for localhost:/howler.js

makes sense. for i seem to only serve one file through socket io:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var howler = require("howler");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log(__dirname);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

my first fix would be to serve the client via /howler.js> but for that i would have to run another http server.

is it possible to include external scripts via the socket io server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var howler = require("howler");
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/howler.js', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/howler.js');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
  console.log(__dirname);
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});


http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```